# How can I delete my bookmarks, "its not there"?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, bookmarks, internet-explorer-10

I want to tidy up... deleteting ALL bookmarks from IE10 and reimport my bookmarks. So in IE10 I've opened up the "Ogranized Favorites" and deleted everything except a empty folder.

If I try to delete that one a Message pops up telling me that its not there. I've checked the path it states that it cant be found but its there alright. If I try to delete that folder I get the same thing; "Could not fin this item".

So how can I og about deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Just because some component of Windows shows you something, does not mean it actually exists.
Windows Explorer, and I assume Internet Explorer, sometimes shows fictitous files and folders, and also sometimes fails to show actual contents of the file system. If you use the command
prompt's "dir" command, with the switch to make "hidden" and "system" files visible, you
can see what's actually there, and remove whatever you like. Your IE bookmarks (usually
known as "favorites"), are located in your user profile directory in the "Favorites" folder,
and consist of files with a ".url" extension.

Also, be aware that Internet Explorer sometimes creates folders under the Favorites folder,
and gives users no say in the matter.